# A multinomial-like expansion

Tags: combinatorics, summation

Let $m,r\in\mathbb N$, and let $S$ be the set of $m$-tuples $J=(j_1,\dots,j_m)\in\mathbb N^m$ such that $j_1+\cdots+j_m=r$. The multinomial theorem asserts that

$$\sum_{J\in S}\binom rJ X^J=(X_1+\dots+X_m)^r\,,$$

where $\dbinom rJ=\dbinom r{j_1,\dots,j_m}$ is the multinomial coefficient, and $X^J=X_1^{j_1}\cdots X_m^{j_m}$.

I would like to know if there is a (nice) formula for the following similar sum:

$$\sum_{J\in S}X^J=?$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is ($[z^r]$ is the coefficient of $z^r$):
$$
[z^r]\prod_{1 \le k \le m} \frac{1}{1 - z X_k}
$$
I very much doubt there is a nice formula for this. Might try taking the logarithm to simplify getting values for the coefficients...